# Java script || or operator condition is not working

Tags: javascript

In the below script I added `or` operator to check the condition, Like if it is "ALL TCP" or "ALL UDP" item must get disabled, Please suggest me to modify the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chgJob(pThis, pRow)
    {
        if ((pThis.value != 'All TCP') || (pThis.value != 'All UDP'))
        {
            $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, false);
        }
        else
        {
            $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `if ((pThis.value != 'All TCP') || (pThis.value != 'All UDP'))` can also be written as `if ((pThis.value == 'All TCP') && (pThis.value == 'All UDP'))`

Comment: @SimonLaing: Incorrect. Your `and` statement will always return false, since `pThis.value` can't possibly be  `'All TCP'` and `'All UDP'` a the same time.

Comment: @Cerbrus, you are right too, misread the `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string can never be equal to `'All TCP'` and equal to `'All UDP'` at the same time, so the condition will always be true.

You want to use the `&&` operator instead of the `||` operator:

```
if ((pThis.value != 'All TCP') && (pThis.value != 'All UDP'))
```

#### Edit:

As Cerbrus pointed out, you don't need the `if` statement at all, you can use the boolean expression directly by inverting it (`x==y || x==z` is the same as `!(x!=y && x!=z)`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chgJob(pThis, pRow) {
    $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, pThis.value == 'All TCP' || pThis.value == 'All UDP');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Since you've got the most votes already, would you want to add [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13698212/1835379) about omitting the `if-else` altogether?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ((pThis.value != 'All TCP') && (pThis.value != 'All UDP'))
```

or :

```
function chgJob(pThis, pRow)
{
    if ((pThis.value == 'All TCP') || (pThis.value == 'All UDP'))
    {
        $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, true);
    }
    else
    {
        $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like has been said already, in your `if-else`, you'll need the `&&` operator, instead of the `||`, but:

You can also remove the `if` altogether, by doing this instead:

```
function chgJob(pThis, pRow) {
    $x_disableItem('f02_' + pRow, (pThis.value == 'All TCP' || pThis.value == 'All UDP'));
}
```

If `pThis.value` is `"ALL TCP"` or `"ALL UDP"`, the item will be disabled.